# Rails private views and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to create a private `view` and `controller`, so that I can only invoke it somehow from the code?

I would like to be able to display dynamic `widgets` in different parts of my application. I thought about creating a `controller` and `view` for them and then rendering them in places I want, however then people will be able to see them just typing the correct URL.

Or maybe I could prevent that with some rule in `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem will be solved using [partial views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), you need to create each widget like a partial view and call each partial in the view that you want to have widgets.

Also you may need to have the variables loaded like a normal view.

Answer (score 0):

you can put [filtters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) in your controller for specific actions. that way only people with specific permissions (admins?) can access it:

```
before_filter :require_login

private     
def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to new_login_url # halts request cycle
    end
end
```